# Convert string from @Input to a ComponentType<T> orTemplateRef<T> for matDialog

Tags: angular

I am new to coding and new to Angular so I thought I would ask for some help. I'm currently looking through the Angular documentation for an answer but sometimes the explanations on here are much better!

Following on from my previous question regarding creating a wrapper service for the MatDialog provide by Angular Material I was wondering if it would be possible to convert a string that is the name of a Component Type to the Component Or Template Reference (ComponentType | TemplateRef) that we pass to MatDialog.open method? Doesn't make sense? I will explain a little better...

Here I have a wrapper service for the MatDialog, notice that we have to pass "componentRef" to the dialog.open method

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MatDialogWrapperService {

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }

    open(componentRef, config = {}) {
        this.dialog.open(componentRef, config);
    }
}
```

Now I can use the wrapper service in a component and pass the componentRef ...

```
import { ModalFormComponent } from './forms/modal-form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-intro-form',
    templateUrl: './intro-form.component.html',
    providers: [MatDialogWrapperService],
    styleUrls: ['./intro-form.component.scss']
})

  constructor(private modalService: MatDialogWrapperService ) {
  }

  modalCall() {
    this.modalService.open(ModalFormComponent, {
        width: '500px'
  });
}
```

Say I want the component that is rendered in the Modal to be dynamic or passed into my component? In the example above it is "hard coded" with the value ModalFormComponent that I have passed into the component using an import statement. Could I hypothetically pass this value in as an @Import() and convert the string value to a type reference? For example, in my HTML something like this

```
<app-intro-form [modalComponent]="'ModalFormComponent'"></app-intro-form>
```

and in my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-intro-form',
    templateUrl: './intro-form.component.html',
    providers: [MatDialogWrapperService],
    styleUrls: ['./intro-form.component.scss']
})

@Input() componentRef: any; // this needs to be wrapped or converted
constructor(private modalService: MatDialogWrapperService ) {}

  modalCall() {
    this.modalService.open(componentRef, {
        width: '500px'
  });
}
```

The `@Input()` would need to be converted to a reference from a string for it to work but I am unsure how to go about this. I am currently trying to teach myself Angular so I realise that sometimes my problems may make no practical sense, but this isn't for a production app... it is so I can learn how to code and code well!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably to have some kind of registry that keeps track of your different components.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentRegistryService{
    public getComponentByName(name: string) {
        switch (name) {
            case "ConfirmComponent":
                return ConfirmComponent;
            ...
        }
    }    
}
```

You can then use that in your wrapper:

```
constructor(private modalService: MatDialogWrapperService, private registry: ComponentRegistryService) {}

  modalCall() {
    this.modalService.open(registry.getComponentByName(componentRef), {
        width: '500px'
  });
}
```